# Sum array by number in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have a numpy array like:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
and another array:
[0,0,1,2,2,1]
I want to sum the items in the first array by group (the second array) and obtain n-groups results in group number order (in this case the result would be [3, 9, 9]). How do I do this in numpy?

Comment: Why do you need numpy for this? Aren't you just using vanilla python lists? If not, what numpy type are you using?

Comment: I need numpy for this because I don't want to loop through the array n-times for n groups, since my array sizes can be arbitrarily large. I'm not using python lists, I was just showing an example data set in brackets. The datatype is int.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089379/most-efficient-way-to-sum-huge-2d-numpy-array-grouped-by-id-column

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this, but here's one way:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(1, 7)
groups = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,1])

unique_groups = np.unique(groups)
sums = []
for group in unique_groups:
    sums.append(data[groups == group].sum())
```

You *can* vectorize things so that there's no for loop at all, but I'd recommend against it. It becomes unreadable, and will require a couple of 2D temporary arrays, which could require large amounts of memory if you have a lot of data.

Edit: Here's one way you could entirely vectorize. Keep in mind that this may (and likely will) be slower than the version above.  (And there may be a better way to vectorize this, but it's late and I'm tired, so this is just the first thing to pop into my head...)

However, keep in mind that this is a bad example... You're really better off (both in terms of speed and readability) with the loop above...

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(1, 7)
groups = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,1])

unique_groups = np.unique(groups)

# Forgive the bad naming here...
# I can't think of more descriptive variable names at the moment...
x, y = np.meshgrid(groups, unique_groups)
data_stack = np.tile(data, (unique_groups.size, 1))

data_in_group = np.zeros_like(data_stack)
data_in_group[x==y] = data_stack[x==y]

sums = data_in_group.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Memory's not an issue and I'd like to avoid loops. How would you vectorize it?

Comment: @Scribble Master - See the edit... There's nothing wrong with looping over the unique groups, though. The second version will probably be slow, and is damned hard to read.  With the loop you're only looping (in python, anyway) over the number of unique groups. The inner comparison `data[groups == group]` will be quite fast.

Comment: What dark magic is this `data[groups == group]` construct? Comparing an array to a scalar yields some kind of slice or view? o_O

Comment: @Karl - `groups == group` yields a boolean array.  You can index by arrays in numpy. This is a very common idiom in numpy (and Matlab).   I find it quite readable (think of it as "where") and it's extremely useful.

Comment: @Joe: Neat, but maybe a bit too magical for my liking. I haven't done very much with Numpy (haven't found as much need for it as I thought I might) - it will take some getting used to.

Comment: @JoeKington Excellent answer! quick and efficient

Comment: How would this work if the data and group are multi dimensional?
E.g. data shape is (k,m,n) and there are j long, it would have to return a sum over dimension k for j bins. Result would have to be j,m,n

Answer (score 57):

The numpy function `bincount` was made exactly for this purpose and I'm sure it will be much faster than the other methods for all sizes of inputs:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ids  = [0,0,1,2,2,1]

np.bincount(ids, weights=data) #returns [3,9,9] as a float64 array
```

The i-th element of the output is the sum of all the `data` elements corresponding to "id" `i`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can confirm this is very fast. About 10 times faster than the sum_by_group method Bi Rico provided on small inputs.

Comment: what if `data` are vectors?

Comment: It looks like the weights argument has to be 1-dimensional. One solution is to run bincount once for each dimension of the vector (i.e. twice if data is a set of 2-d vectors). A slight modification of Peter's answer should also work.

Comment: Great method. Note that bincount requires `int` ids.

Comment: Not that all the ids you expect to be present need to be present for this to make the most sense.

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround for `float` ids?

Answer (score 30):

This is a vectorized method of doing this sum based on the implementation of numpy.unique. According to my timings it is up to 500 times faster than the loop method and up to 100 times faster than the histogram method.

```
def sum_by_group(values, groups):
    order = np.argsort(groups)
    groups = groups[order]
    values = values[order]
    values.cumsum(out=values)
    index = np.ones(len(groups), 'bool')
    index[:-1] = groups[1:] != groups[:-1]
    values = values[index]
    groups = groups[index]
    values[1:] = values[1:] - values[:-1]
    return values, groups
```

Answer (score 7):

If the groups are indexed by consecutive integers, you can abuse the `numpy.histogram()` function to get the result:

```
data = numpy.arange(1, 7)
groups = numpy.array([0,0,1,2,2,1])
sums = numpy.histogram(groups, 
                       bins=numpy.arange(groups.min(), groups.max()+2), 
                       weights=data)[0]
# array([3, 9, 9])
```

This will avoid any Python loops.

Answer (score 7):

I tried scripts from everyone and my considerations are:

| User | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | Will only work if you have few groups. |
| kevpie | Too slow because of loops (this is not pythonic way). |
| Bi_Rico and Sven | Nice performance, but will only work for Int32 (if the sum goes over 2^32/2 it will fail |
| Alex | Is the fastest one, the best solution for sum. |

But if you want more flexibility and the possibility to group by other statistics use [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

data = np.arange(10000000)
unique_groups = np.arange(1000)
groups = unique_groups.repeat(10000)

ndimage.sum(data, groups, unique_groups)
```

This is good because you have many statistics to group (sum, mean, variance, ...).

Comment: This solution is quite neat.

Answer (score 5):

You're all wrong!  The best way to do it is:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ix = [0,0,1,2,2,1]
accum = np.zeros(np.max(ix)+1)
np.add.at(accum, ix, a)
print accum
> array([ 3.,  9.,  9.])
```

Comment: Actually you should probably just use Alex's `np.bincount` answer

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the `numpy` tag but in case you don't mind using `pandas`, this task becomes an one-liner:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(1, 7)
groups = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data, 'groups': groups})
```

So `df` then looks like this:

```
   data  groups
0     1       0
1     2       0
2     3       1
3     4       2
4     5       2
5     6       1
```

Now you can use the functions `groupby()` and `sum()`

```
print(df.groupby(['groups'], sort=False).sum())
```

which gives you the desired output

```
        data
groups      
0          3
1          9
2          9
```

By default, the dataframe would be sorted, therefore I use the flag `sort=False` which might improve speed for huge dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note for Alex's answer:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ids  = [0,0,1,2,2,1]
np.bincount(ids, weights=data) #returns [3,9,9] as a float64 array
```

In case your indexes are not *consecutive* you might get stuck thinking why you keep getting a lot of zeros.

For instance:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ids  = [1,1,3,5,5,3]
np.bincount(ids, weights=data)
```

will give you:

```
array([0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 9])
```

which obviously means it builds all unique bins from 0 to *max* id in the list. And then return sums for each bin.

Answer (score 1):

I tried different methods to do this and I found that indeed using `np.bincount` is the fastest. See Alex's answer

```
    import numpy as np
    import random
    import time
    
    size = 10000
    ngroups = 10
    
    groups = np.random.randint(low=0,high=ngroups,size=size)
    values = np.random.rand(size)
    
    
    # Test 1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.zeros(ngroups)
    for i in range(size):
        result[groups[i]] += values[i]
    print('Test 1 took:',time.time()-beg)
    
    # Test 2                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.zeros(ngroups)
    for g,v in zip(groups,values):
        result[g] += v
    print('Test 2 took:',time.time()-beg)
    
    # Test 3                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.zeros(ngroups)
    for g in np.unique(groups):
        wh = np.where(groups == g)
        result[g] = np.sum(values[wh[0]])
    print('Test 3 took:',time.time()-beg)
    
    
    # Test 4                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.zeros(ngroups)
    for g in np.unique(groups):
        wh = groups == g
        result[g] = np.sum(values, where = wh)
    print('Test 4 took:',time.time()-beg)
    
    # Test 5                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.array([np.sum(values[np.where(groups == g)[0]]) for g in np.unique(groups) ])
    print('Test 5 took:',time.time()-beg)
    
    # Test 6                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.array([np.sum(values, where = groups == g) for g in np.unique(groups) ])
    print('Test 6 took:',time.time()-beg)
    
    # Test 7                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    beg = time.time()
    result = np.bincount(groups, weights = values)
    print('Test 7 took:',time.time()-beg)
```

Results:

```
    Test 1 took: 0.005615234375
    Test 2 took: 0.004812002182006836
    Test 3 took: 0.0006084442138671875
    Test 4 took: 0.0005099773406982422
    Test 5 took: 0.000499725341796875
    Test 6 took: 0.0004980564117431641
    Test 7 took: 1.9073486328125e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that works for summing objects of any dimension, grouped by values of any type (not only int):

```
grouping = np.array([1.1, 10, 1.1, 15])
to_sum = np.array([
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0.5, 0.3],
    [2, 5],
])

groups, element_group_ixs = np.unique(grouping, return_inverse=True)
accum = np.zeros((groups.shape[0], *to_sum.shape[1:]))
np.add.at(accum, element_group_ixs, to_sum)
```

results in:

```
groups = array([ 1.1, 10. , 15. ])
accum = array([
    [1.5, 0.3],
    [0. , 1. ],
    [2. , 5. ]
])
```

(np.add.at idea taken from Peter's answer)

Answer (score -1):

A pure python implementation:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
g = [0,0,1,2,2,1]

from itertools import izip
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

def group_sum(l, g):
    groups = defaultdict(int)
    for li, gi in izip(l, g):
        groups[gi] += li
    return map(itemgetter(1), sorted(groups.iteritems()))

print group_sum(l, g)

[3, 9, 9]
```