# numpy, sums of subsets with no iterations

Tags: numpy

#### Scenario:

I have an array `values` with some values.
These elements are divided into groups.
The grouping information is stored into another array, said `groups`. This array has the same dimension of `values`. The i-th element of `groups` tells at which group belongs the i-th element of `values`.

I need to compute the partial sum ov `values` for each group.

#### Example:

For instance, in the case I have 3 groups:

```py
values = [0.1, 0.5, 10e-5, 12., 10e3, 0.2, 15., 10e-6]
groups = [1  , 1  , 2    , 3  , 3   , 1  , 3  , 2    ]
```

I'd like to compute this array

```py
sums = [0.1+0.5+0.2, 10e-5+10e-6, 12.+10e3+15.]
```

#### The problem:

Since I have a huge number of elements (some millions), and some thousand groups, I use numpy arrays to tread these objects. I'm actually searching for something with complexity O(N), with no loops over the number of groups. Also, any performance improvement is welcome.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```py
for group_id in xrange(0,number_of_groups):
    sums[i]=numpy.sum(values[groups==i])
```

This code makes `number_of_groups*number_of_elements` operations.

This code is too slow, I'm searching for something which  **does not** loop over the groups.

#### Possible C solution:

It is possible to do this work in C. The code in C could be:

```c
for(i=0;i<n_elements;i++)
    sums[groups[i]]+=values[i]
```

As you can see this code has only `number_of_elements` iterations. There are no iterations in the array of groups.

#### So..

How could I write the same in numpy?

Comment: Yep, thanks, corrected as you said.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373631/sum-array-by-number-in-numpy

Comment: You're right. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I searched for "numpy group by" to find it, incidentally.

Comment: BTW, do you know if there is something similar for the `min` operation?

Comment: Definitely worth asking a question, it would be interesting to see some solutions.