# How to merge and sum duplicates in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
   [2016-10-20 00:00:00, 6, 17],
   [2016-10-20 00:00:00, 0, 21],
   [2017-09-11 00:00:00, 7, 22],
   [2017-09-11 00:00:00, 5, 30],
   [2017-09-11 00:00:00, 2, 40]
```

Is there an easy way to merge the the rows with the same dates and sum up the values belonging to the same date?

For the example above, It should look like this:

```
   [2016-10-20 00:00:00, 6, 38],
   [2017-09-11 00:00:00, 14, 92]
```

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373631/sum-array-by-number-in-numpy

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid NumPy array format. Also, are the dates sorted in that sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2016-10-20 00:00:00', 6, 17],
    ['2016-10-20 00:00:00', 0, 21],
    ['2017-09-11 00:00:00', 7, 22],
    ['2017-09-11 00:00:00', 5, 30],
    ['2017-09-11 00:00:00', 2, 40]
])

d.groupby([0]).aggregate(sum)

#                       1   2
# 0
# 2016-10-20 00:00:00   6  38
# 2017-09-11 00:00:00  14  92
```

Note that [`pandas.DataFrame` accepts a `numpy` array as input](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe).