# Numpy combining values within a 2-D array based on index

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I have a numpy array based around this format `[[x,y],[x,y]...]` and with this I would like to combine the `y` values where the `x`'s are the same

Example `array = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,4],[4,6],[2,2],[3,7],[1,9],[4,16],[5,1],[5,2],[0,0]]`

I would like this to become `newArray = [[0,0],[1,10],[2,6],[3,7],[4,22],[5,3]]` - it doesn't have to be ordered

As if now i can't think  of a way to do this simply and efficiently, it might help to add in my actual array uses timestamps as my `x` value such as `Timestamp('2018-05-05 00:00:00')` and is 183083 in size which isn't too bad.

Any help appricated!

Comment: Did one of the solutions below help? Feel free to accept one if it did (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Pure `numpy` solutions are available, if performance is an issue: [Sum array by number in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373631/sum-array-by-number-in-numpy)

Below is a dictionary-based approach using `collections.defaultdict`. This works by iterating each row in your array and summing values by key.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

A = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,4],[4,6],[2,2],[3,7],[1,9],[4,16],[5,1],[5,2],[0,0]])

d = defaultdict(int)
for i, j in A:
    d[i] += j

res = np.array(sorted(d.items()))

print(res)

array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1, 10],
       [ 2,  6],
       [ 3,  7],
       [ 4, 22],
       [ 5,  3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the `collections.Counter`

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

ar = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,4],[4,6],[2,2],[3,7],[1,9],[4,16],[5,1],[5,2],[0,0], [20,0]])

repeated = [item for item, count in Counter(ar[:,0]).iteritems() if count > 1]
non_repeated = [item for item in range(len(ar)) if item not in repeated]

new_arr = []
for element in repeated:
    new_arr.append(np.sum(ar[np.where(ar[:,0]==element)],axis=0))
new_arr = np.asanyarray(new_arr)
new_arr[:,0] = new_arr[:,0]/2.
new_arr = ar[non_repeated]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical grouping-operation. numoy does not support these cleanly out of the box, but the [numpy-indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package does (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
keys, sums = npi.group_by(A[:, 0]).sum(A[:, 1])
```

This solution works in a fully vectorized manner; so no for loops over the array in python, and also generalizes to a lot of other scenarios. It can be installed using pip or conda.